# Fetch data from database in jasper report and display it in text field

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to fetch the date from the database and then need to manipulate on that date to display the due date in the jasper report.

Table name is: ACCOUNTINGLOCATION

Column name: CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE  (dd//mm//yyyy time)

Once we fetch the CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE from databse , Use this date as base to generate the due date in the text field. Due date is nothing but the next month 14th.

Suppose the CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE = 21.01.2019 then in the report I should display the value as 14.02.2019( dd/mm/yyyy)

For Jan the due date will be feb 14. for Feb due date will be march 14 and so on.

Can you please help me with this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin date/time functions to compute the date:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[EDATE(DATE(YEAR($F{CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE}), MONTH($F{CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE}), 14), 1)]]></textFieldExpression>
```

With `DATE(YEAR(..), MONTH(..), 14)` you get 14th on the current month, and then the `EDATE` function is used to add a number of months (1 in this case) to the date.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response. But how can i fetch the  "CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE" from database? do i need to use the query string ? CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE is in the format dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00 format. I  tried your code but while building the project it is giving the error.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to write a query to fetch data from the database.  As in "select CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE from ACCOUNTINGLOCATION".  Declare the CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE as java.sql.Date, it's safer than passing dates as strings.

Comment: Hi I have declared like this : <parameter name="CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE " class="java.sql.Date"></parameter> <queryString>
 <![CDATA[SELECT CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE FROM AccountingLocation]]>
 </queryString>
and then used below in the text field <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[EDATE(DATE(YEAR($F{CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE}), MONTH($F{CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE}), 14), 1)]]></textFieldExpression>  Am i doing something wrong here? Im getting error in query string. Please help.

Comment: CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE should be a field, and not a parameter.  "Im getting error in query string" - please elaborate and include the full error.

Comment: Hi, i have declared CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE  as a field, and <queryString>
 <![CDATA[Select CurrentAccountingDate from AccountingLocation]]>
 </queryString> and used the <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[EDATE(DATE(YEAR($F{CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE}), MONTH($F{CURRENTACCOUNTINGDATE}), 14), 1)]]></textFieldExpression> but i can see in error log its showing unhandled event loop exception and in report log its throwing net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unknown column name CurrentAccountingDate in result set. ..

Comment: Hi multiple query string is not allowed in single jasper? there is already one query string exist in my report [‎2/‎14/‎2019 9:59 AM]  Ganesh Pallavi:  
<queryString>
  <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM V_DebtorOverdueInterestInvBG
WHERE ClientNumber=$P{ClientNumber}
AND AgreementNumber=$P{AgreementNumber}
AND DebtorNumber=$P{DebtorNumber}
AND AccountNumber=$P{AccountNumber}]]>
 </queryString> 
 
Please assist :(

Comment: You can have one query for the main report dataset (used to fill the report detail bands), and one query for each subdataset (which can be used to fill list, table or chart elements.